# Rails model with rubocop error - specify an `:inverse_of` option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got two models with optional relations `has_many` - `belongs_to`, like below:

```
class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'cms_journey_id'
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :journey, optional: true, foreign_key: 'cms_journey_id'
end
```

As you see the relation is based on non-standard `foregin_key` name (both models are linked with each other by record called `cms_journey_id`). After I added `foreign_key: 'cms_journey_id'` I'm getting Rubocop error in both models:

```
Rails/InverseOf: Specify an `:inverse_of` option
```

Comment: What's your question? Maybe read a little on `inverse_of` ... https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/

Comment: @maxpleaner great link it really helps, thanks for that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify the inverse relationships, Rails does its best to infer the inverse association on a model (at least for `has_many`, `has_one`, and `belongs_to` associations) using the class names as the basis for its guesses.

But anytime you use a scope or set non-standard naming, you need to explicitly tell Rails how to navigate the associations using `inverse_of`. In your case:

```rb
class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy, 
                        foreign_key: 'cms_journey_id', 
                        inverse_of: :journey
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :journey, optional: true, 
                       foreign_key: 'cms_journey_id', 
                       inverse_of: :activities
end
```

For future reference, the Rubocop documentation on individual cops is generally good and clear, and includes examples of 'good' and 'bad'. Just search for the cop name (e.g. 'Rails/InverseOf') and you're in good shape.